# Twilio Merge Child Recordings

Tags: twilio

I am trying to build an API which can Onhold both inbound and outbound calls, what I basically do is, update the CallResource and forward it to a Play command when I want to hold on and connect to the agent if I want to resume the call.

This works good, I am able to hold on/ resume call successfully.

I have seen some questions and answers regarding this, Twilio support suggests to use Conference option for that, isn't there may be a new solution (or other solution) for this.

What I want is actually merge child call recordings, isn't there an option for this?

[image: Child Recordings]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to concatenate call recordings within Twilio, what I would recommend is to download the files and [concatenate them with something like ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#samecodec). You should be able to script this too.

Comment: thanks, we don't want to use any additional resources for this process, so we decided to handle onhold / resume thing on the front end. We switch the input source using "setInputTracksFromStream" from microphone to mp3 file when we want to hold on the call. So we have a single recording for that call.

Comment: Nice workaround! Glad you have something figured out for this.